# R: How to calculate lag for multiple columns by group for data table

Tags: r, data.table, lag, difference

I would like to calculate the diff of variables in a data table, grouped by id.  Here is some sample data.  The data is recorded at a sample rate of 1 Hz.  I would like to estimate the first and second derivatives (speed, acceleration)

```
df <- read.table(text='x y id
                 1 2 1
                 2 4 1
                 3 5 1
                 1 8 2
                 5 2 2
                 6 3 2',header=TRUE)
dt<-data.table(df)
```

Expected output

```
# dx dy id
# NA NA 1
# 1  2  1
# 1  1  1
# NA NA 2
# 4  -6  2
# 1 1    2
```

Here's what I've tried

```
dx_dt<-dt[, diff:=c(NA,diff(dt[,'x',with=FALSE])),by = id]
```

Output is

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(dt, , `:=`(diff, c(NA, diff(dt[, "x", with = FALSE]))),  : 
  unused argument (by = id)
```

As pointed out by Akrun, the 'speed' terms (dx, dy) can be obtained using either data table or plyr.  However, I'm unable to understand the calculation well enough to extend it to acceleration terms.  So, how to calculate the 2nd lag terms?

```
dt[, c('dx', 'dy'):=lapply(.SD, function(x) c(NA, diff(x))),
+ by=id]
```

produces

```
   x y id dx dy
1: 1 2  1 NA NA
2: 2 4  1  1  2
3: 3 5  1  1  1
4: 1 8  2 NA NA
5: 5 2  2  4 -6
6: 6 3  2  1  1
```

How to expand to get a second diff, or the diff of dx, dy?

```
   x y id dx dy  dx2  dy2
1: 1 2  1 NA NA   NA   NA
2: 2 4  1  1  2   NA   NA
3: 3 5  1  1  1    0   -1
4: 1 8  2 NA NA   NA   NA
5: 5 2  2  4 -6   NA   NA
6: 6 3  2  1  1   -3    7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
 setnames(dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) c(NA,diff(x))), by=id], 
                2:3, c('dx', 'dy'))[]
 #    id dx dy
  #1:  1 NA NA
  #2:  1  1  2
  #3:  1  1  1
  #4:  2 NA NA
  #5:  2  4 -6
  #6:  2  1  1
```

Another option would be to use `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
     group_by(id) %>%
     mutate_each(funs(c(NA,diff(.))))%>%
     rename(dx=x, dy=y)
```

#### Update

You can repeat the step twice

```
dt[, c('dx', 'dy'):=lapply(.SD, function(x) c(NA, diff(x))), by=id]
dt[,c('dx2', 'dy2'):= lapply(.SD, function(x) c(NA, diff(x))),
                                            by=id, .SDcols=4:5]
 dt
 #   x y id dx dy dx2 dy2
 #1: 1 2  1 NA NA  NA  NA
 #2: 2 4  1  1  2  NA  NA
 #3: 3 5  1  1  1   0  -1
 #4: 1 8  2 NA NA  NA  NA
 #5: 5 2  2  4 -6  NA  NA
 #6: 6 3  2  1  1  -3   7
```

Or we can use the `shift` function from `data.table`

```
dt[, paste0("d", c("x", "y")) := .SD - shift(.SD), by = id
  ][, paste0("d", c("x2", "y2")) := .SD - shift(.SD) , by =  id, .SDcols = 4:5 ]
```

Comment: If the exact column names are not relevant, one could just do `dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) c(NA, diff(x))), by = id]` right? (which is the same as your answer, at the core)

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes, I did that earlier, but thought that the OP wanted to rename the columns. or may be use `setnames`

Comment: I can't understand the calculation, so I'm going to modify the question to include dx2, dy2.

Comment: @John Please do modify the question.  Here, the `lapply(.SD,..)` is doing the `diff` for each of the column and we specify the grouping variable with `by=.`

Comment: @John Or you could do it one step, itself

Comment: @akrun How have you been? I haven't properly checked SO for one week, but I just came across this post. I like `mutate_each(funs(c(NA,diff(.))))`. I haven't thought about using `c()` in the function. This was new to me. +1 :)

Comment: I've used this as a dupe target. It would be nice if the answer were updated to use `shift`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looks like I may have duped wrong. OP title refers to lag, when actually it wants `diff`... anyone can feel free to reverse my dupe (from a question actually about lags) or link a better one.